# How can I change my cursor with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I just had an answer on how to do this:

CSS

```
body.ajaxloading {     cursor:wait; }
```

jQuery

```
function enableLoadingIcon() {     
   $(body).addClass('ajaxloading'); 
} 
function disableLoadingIcon() {     
   $(body).addClass('ajaxloading'); 
}
```

However when I try to implement it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone see what the reason is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you wouldn't have to declare the class in your CSS if you just manually injected the CSS using jQuery like so:

```
function enableLoadingIcon() {     
   $(document.body).css ("cursor", "wait"); 
} 
function disableLoadingIcon() {     
   $(document.body).css("cursor", "auto"); 
}
```

Comment: You could also set the cursor back to "default" instead of "auto". As I understand it, "auto" allows the browser to choose the default to set it back to, and "default" sets the cursor back to the system default. Usually they'll equate to the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

`$(body)` is wrong. It is actually `$("body")`.

```
function enableLoadingIcon() {     
   $('body').addClass('ajaxloading'); 
} 
function disableLoadingIcon() {     
   $('body').removeClass('ajaxloading'); 
}
```

or, even faster,  `$(document.body)`

```
function enableLoadingIcon() {     
   $(document.body).addClass('ajaxloading'); 
} 
function disableLoadingIcon() {     
   $(document.body).removeClass('ajaxloading'); 
}
```

Comment: `$(document.body)` is faster. DOM traversal vs `getElementsByTagName()`

Comment: @Martin - Just noticed. I think it should also be removeClass. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You just need `$('body')` instead of `$(body)`